# Help needed in solving a question of quantitative aptitude which is sort of a puzzle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying these questions of quantitative aptitude and unfortunately unable to solve them so, I need help.

Adding image of the question->

[image]

I have no idea what is the clue hidden in that statement.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: I think this is more suited to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24728/the-clue-is-hidden-in-this-statement

Comment: @BrianM.Scott uhm, four times?

Comment: @Hagen: Clearly I need new glasses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue statement is self-referential. This suggests that the solution is "X marks the spot"

Comment: Answer is 9  not 10